# Thymeleaf: define URL in the controller for the Datatables

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, thymeleaf

I had this piece of code in my Thymeleaf template that was working fine

```
var ajaxUrl = /*[[@{/api/users/{user}/menus/vegan/datatableList(user=${#authentication.principal.id})}]]*/ ""


    var table = $('#menuTable').DataTable( {
        order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        select: true,
        bLengthChange: false,
        stateSave: true,
        pageLength: 20,
        ajax: ajaxUrl, 
           "columns": [
               { data: 'id' },
               { data: 'desc' }
           ] 
    });
```

I made a change and now I define the URL in the controller as follows:

```
model.addAttribute("ajaxUrl", "/api/users/{user}/menus/vegan/datatableList(user=${#authentication.principal.id})");
```

and this code in the Thymeleaf template, but the page is not working anymore

```
var ajaxUrl = /*[[@{ajaxUrl)}]]*/ ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is not working anymore. This:

```
@{/api/users/{user}/menus/vegan/datatableList(user=${#authentication.principal.id})}
```

is a thymeleaf expression, parsed by thymeleaf.

While your second attempt `@{ajaxUrl}` isn't even using a variable -- it is simply resolves to the url `href="ajaxUrl"`.   You can get closer with `@{${ajaxUrl}}`, but even that won't do exactly what you want.  The closest you can get to supplying the ajax variable from your controller would be:

```
// Controller
model.addAttribute("ajaxUrl", "/api/users/{user}/menus/vegan/datatableList");

// JavaScript
var ajaxUrl = /*[[@{${ajaxUrl}(user=${#authentication.principal.id})}]]*/ "";
```

If you want to pass the entire url, you have to compute the user id yourself.  For example:

```
// Controller
String user = "1"; // You need to supply the user id here. (However you get that in java.)
model.addAttribute("ajaxUrl", "/api/users/" + user + "/menus/vegan/datatableList");

// JavaScript
var ajaxUrl = /*[[@{${ajaxUrl}}]]*/ "";
```